# Sequentially executing functions in an array with reduce and promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I have an array of functions

`var functionArray = [function1, function2, function3];`

The functions looks like this. All are identical

```
var function2 = (value, callback) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        value++;
        callback(null, value);
    }, 2000);
}
```

I want to execute these functions sequentially using `reduce` and `promises`. But the below code is not working. I am not able to get my head around it.

```
var wrapper = (functionName, value) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        functionName(value, (error, returnedValue) => {
            console.log(returnedValue);
            resolve(returnedValue);
        });
    });
}

var execute = function () {
    return functionArray.reduce((promise, currentFunction) => {
        return promise.then((value = 10) => {
            wrapper(currentFunction, value);
        });
    }, Promise.resolve());
};
```

When I invoke `execute` the value 11 gets printed three times immediately. Am I missing something here?

Live Snippet:

```js
var function1 = (value, callback) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        value++;
        callback(null, value);
    }, 2000);
}
var function2 = (value, callback) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        value++;
        callback(null, value);
    }, 2000);
}
var function3 = (value, callback) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        value++;
        callback(null, value);
    }, 2000);
}

var wrapper = (functionName, value) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        functionName(value, (error, returnedValue) => {
            console.log(returnedValue);
            resolve(returnedValue);
        });
    });
}

var execute = function () {
    return functionArray.reduce((promise, currentFunction) => {
        return promise.then((value = 10) => {
            wrapper(currentFunction, value);
        });
    }, Promise.resolve());
};

var functionArray = [function1, function2, function3];
execute();
```

Comment: *"I want to execute these functions sequentially using reduce and promises"* Why promises, specifically, when the functions don't provide promises?

Comment: I don't know, just wanna try, in theory if I write a wrapper which converts the callbacks to promises it should work right?

Comment: I've updated your question with a live snippet, but it doesn't do what you describe. It does show 11 three times, but not immediately; it waits 2 seconds. Is that also what you're seeing, or is the snippet not an accurate reflection of your code?

Comment: You have to call that function one after another. It seems all functions called after 2 secs.

Comment: yeah all the functions are executing simultaneously. Even though it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here (`***`):

```
return functionArray.reduce((promise, currentFunction) => {
    return promise.then((value = 10) => {
        wrapper(currentFunction, value); // ***
    });
}, Promise.resolve());
```

You're not *returning* the promise that `wrapper` produces, so the result of the `then` callback is `undefined`, and so the promise you're calling it on isn't resolved to that new promise. So `wrapper` is called three times one right after another, and two seconds later, the timeouts occur. It also accounts for why you get 11 three times: Subsequent calls don't see the result of the previous one (they see `undefined`), so you're getting the default of 10 for `value` each time.

If you return the promise, either:

```
return functionArray.reduce((promise, currentFunction) => {
    return promise.then((value = 10) => {
        return wrapper(currentFunction, value);
// −−−−−^^^^^^
    });
}, Promise.resolve());
```

or:

```
return functionArray.reduce((promise, currentFunction) => {
    return promise.then((value = 10) => wrapper(currentFunction, value));
//−−^^^^^^
}, Promise.resolve());
```

...it spreads them out as expected, and they see and use the return value of the previous call:

```js
var function1 = (value, callback) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        value++;
        callback(null, value);
    }, 2000);
}
var function2 = (value, callback) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        value++;
        callback(null, value);
    }, 2000);
}
var function3 = (value, callback) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        value++;
        callback(null, value);
    }, 2000);
}

var wrapper = (functionName, value) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        functionName(value, (error, returnedValue) => {
            console.log(returnedValue);
            resolve(returnedValue);
        });
    });
}

var execute = function () {
    return functionArray.reduce((promise, currentFunction) => {
        return promise.then((value = 10) => {
            return wrapper(currentFunction, value);
        });
    }, Promise.resolve());
};

var functionArray = [function1, function2, function3];
execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

the return values are not correct.

Parameter is always 10.

```
  return wrapper(currentFunction, value, timeout);
```

See:

https://jsfiddle.net/js1n6xL3/3/

Maybe this can help you too: 
https://gist.github.com/anvk/5602ec398e4fdc521e2bf9940fd90f84